# javascript functions to simulate classes, best practices?

Tags: javascript, class, function

I noticed that i can write functions like the one below to simulate classes. I want to know if this is the most up-to-date way of doing it. Any comments appreciated. Thanks

```
function Apple(type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = function () {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    };
}

var apple = new Apple('testapple');
apple.color = 'blue';
console.log(apple.getInfo());
```

Comment: vbulletin forums use the same thing. take a look
http://km-basicresearch.com/tnsatadmins/js/vbulletin_textedit.js
i think it's ok.

Comment: Please, do yourself a favor and just use CoffeeScript... It's so much easier to write OO-like code. You write the code in CoffeeScript and it compiles it into JavaScript so it can co-exist with other JS files. Read more at http://coffeescript.org

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code works fine but not efficient enought as it gives each instance an `getInfo` function. This could be avoided. You could use the following patterns to simulate classes in JS.

### Basic Pattern

To simulate a **class property/method**, you set properties/method on the Constructor function.

```
function Apple() {};
Apple.classProperty = some_value;
Apple.classMethod = some_method;
```

To simulate an **instance property**, you set inside the Constructor functions (as you did in your code):

```
function Apple() {
  this.property = some_instance_value;
};
```

To simulate an **instance method**, you setup functions in the `Constructor.prototype` which will be shared across all its instances

```
function Apple() {};
Apple.prototype.instanceMethod = function () {...};
```

### Advanced Pattern

If you want to set private/privileged method, [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) has very useful patterns available.

Private Method - only available to the constructor:

```
function Constructor(...) {
var that = this;
var membername = value;
function membername(...) {...}

}
```

Privileged Method - can access private method and is accesible to the public:

```
function Constructor(...) {
this.membername = function (...) {...};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I dont see the problem with each instance getting the method though, care to elaborate that?

Comment: JS will allocate more memory to hold each instance methods in your case. If you use those instance intensively, will affect performance alot

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great summary. Too bad IE, even 11, still not support modern ECMAScript classes.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with this implementation.

There are so many patterns in JavaScript. Please have a look.

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

I also found this site is very helpful

http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/