# Need to use Inheritance, Encapsulation, abstraction in Js

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm Trying to use Inheritance, Encapsulation, abstraction and Object concepts in my code. but i have no idea how to use that in the following code. How to change my code in to the new concepts. i added the fiddle in the below link.

```
function createTable() {

  tableContainer.appendChild(table);
  if ((table.nodeValue) != 0) {
    table.innerHTML = "";
  }
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(row);

  headcell = document.createElement('th');
  row.appendChild(headcell);
  headcell.innerHTML = "Select";

  headcell = document.createElement('th');
  row.appendChild(headcell);
  headcell.innerHTML = "Sl.No";

  Object.keys(obj[0]).forEach(function(val) {
    headcell = document.createElement('th');
    row.appendChild(headcell);
    headcell.innerHTML = val;
  });

  headcell = document.createElement('th');
  row.appendChild(headcell);
  headcell.innerHTML = "Action";
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajaovi/wum4mzoc/)

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Why do you want to do OOP? You want to split your function into several functions?

Comment: In JS POO, the function is the constructor. To add methods, modify the prototype.

    function MyClass() {}
    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {}

Comment: I just want to use inheritance, polymorphism, encapsulation concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You'd maybe better have a look at the next generation of Javascript : [ES2015](http://es6-features.org/#ClassInheritance) (formerly ES6) or to [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) which is a superset of Javascript. They both integrate the class concepts.

The constraint is that ES2015 is not well supported by browsers yet so both need to be transpiled to classical Javascript (ES5).

The classical way in ES5 is done by using constructors (inpired by [this](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) page):

```
//constructor method
function Apple (type) {
    //"public" property
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";

    //private variable, only visible in the scope of the constructor 
    logInfo(this.getInfo());

    //public method
    this.getInfo = function() {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    };

    //private method
    function logInfo(info){
        console.log(info);
    }
}

//instancitation
var myApple = new Apple("macintosh");
//You can access public properties
myApple.color="red";
console.log(myApple.getInfo());
```

Have also a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242985/1153988)